# Is there a limitation on the values ​that Einstein tensor $G_{\mu\nu}$ can take?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, curvature, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Is there a limitation on the values ​​that [Einstein tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_tensor) $G_{\mu\nu}$ can take?

For example:

1. Is it always bigger than zero?
2. What is the highest amount that can be taken by it?
3. What is the smallest amount it can get?
4. Is it always positive and non-zero?

Comment: Apart from the values $G_{\mu \nu}$ can take (in some coordinate system), it also satisfies, as a function, the differential constraint of Bianchi identity: $\nabla^\mu G_{\mu \nu}=0$.

Answer (score 3):

In general, the answer is that there is no generic constraint in the sense mentioned above. For example, in the case of de Sitter metric, 
\begin{align}
G_{\mu\nu} = -\Lambda g_{\mu\nu}\,,
\end{align}
where $g_{\mu\nu}$ for static patch of de Sitter spacetime can be given by line element
\begin{equation}
ds^2 = -(1-\Lambda r^2/3)dt^2+\frac{dr^2}{1-\Lambda r^2/3} +r^2d\Omega^2\,.
\end{equation}
For this particular chart, where $r>0$, it is clear that $g_{tt}\in (-1,\infty)$ while $g_{rr} \in (-\infty,1)$. The Poincare chart of AdS spacetime has diagonal elements $g_{\mu\mu}\in (0,\infty)$ for all $\mu$. Also, since $G_{\mu\nu}$ is a tensor, its elements change value even by simple coordinate transformation, so the constraints (1)-(4) do not really make sense. On the other hand, there are constraints one can ask about e.g. $G_{\mu\nu}u^\mu u^\nu$, which is closely related to energy condition. This makes sense because the contraction with four-velocity is a scalar so its magnitude is coordinate-independent.

Answer (score 0):

@Everiana Four-velocity of what? In general I don't understand the question. Is the OP assuming that Einstein's equations are at work? Then it's tantamount to put the same question on $T_{\mu\nu}$. And then I do understand what $u_\mu$ means. Otherwise it could be a generic question about a (1,3) semi-riemannian manifold. In that case
only invariant expressions like 
$g^{\mu \nu} G_{\mu\nu}$ or 
$G^{\mu\nu} G_{\mu\nu}$ could be constrained but I'm unaware of such constraints.

Comment: Four-velocity of any observer in the spacetime. The strong/dominant energy conditions in general relativity, for example, restricts plausible stress-energy (and hence Einstein tensor) by what these observers can possibly see. Null energy condition uses null vector $k^\mu$ instead of observer four-velocity. $G_{\mu\nu}$ alone can change by some crazy coordinate transformations so any reasonable constraints should appear as a scalar invariant like $G^\mu_\mu$ or $G_{\mu\nu}u^\mu u^\nu$ or $G_{\mu\nu}k^\mu k^\nu$, though sometimes it could be like divergences $\nabla^\mu G_{\mu\nu}$.